# Are there SNOT models with instructions for beginners?

Tags: snot

I would like to introduce SNOT building to my daughter.  I have used this method only a few times myself and when I did, I was just messing around.  I feel it would be simpler and less frustrating for my daughter if we had models and instructions similar to what a regular set would give you.  When teaching children and even for a beginner like myself, it would be great to have step by step tutorials including pictures and an end goal to build confidence using the SNOT method.

I saw that there is a website for learning SNOT techniques but it mainly shows how to put different types of bricks together.  Does anyone know of SNOT models with instructions suitable for beginners?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chris McVeigh has some nice [LEGO projects](http://www.chrismcveigh.com/cm/lego_projects.html) on his website that use SNOT techniques.  Many of the projects have PDF instruction guides.

I stumbled on his work after seeing his [LEGO ornaments](http://www.chrismcveigh.com/cm/lego_ornaments.html) a few years back.  Now that the Christmas season is beginning, a few of those ornaments would be a fun way to introduce this technique to your daughter!

Answer (score 1):

There are tools to generate 3D LDraw models which will use SNOT techniques to make sure the overall structure looks nice, most notable:

- [Bram's Sphere Generator](http://lego.bldesign.org/sphere/)
- [LSculpt](http://lego.bldesign.org/LSculpt/index_old.html)

Depending on her age, your daughter should be able to build the small yellow bunny on that last page, and the result is a very good illustration of why SNOT is useful.

[Bram's Flicker page](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bram/) also shows quite a lot of possible SNOT techniques holds a lot of good inspiration as well.

Comment: Seeing the other answer so far is about Christmas, and this one is about Easter, I propose the next one should be about, say, Halloween.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't have every SNOT technique, and they call it "sideways building", the official LEGO Master Builder Academy series is really quite good and introduces quite a few very good advanced techniques. I felt they were more than worth the money for my nephews.

Comment: I just wish they'd be available globally

Comment: And, you forgot Halloween.

Comment: Didn't realize they have a limited distribution.